# Group by Dynamic query in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have simple question about dynamic query in liferay..
How can i use group by in dynamic query

> For ex: select date_,count(*) from Clipping group by date_;

How can i do this in liferay dynamic query?

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = ClippingLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery();

    ProjectionList projectionList = ProjectionFactoryUtil.projectionList();

    projectionList.add(ProjectionFactoryUtil.groupProperty("date"));
    projectionList.add(ProjectionFactoryUtil.rowCount());

    dynamicQuery.setProjection(projectionList);

    List<Object[]> results = ClippingLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(dynamicQuery);
```

Comment: I tried above code but it throws classcast exception java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.dbservice.model.Clipping----------<liferay-ui:search-container-row
  className="com.dbservice.model.Clipping"
  keyProperty="ClippingId" modelVar="item">....What is the solution???

Comment: This looks like a completely different problem... Have you tried to execute that piece of code independently from anything else? No SearchContainer, just that piece of code... and see if if throws exception or not.

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501584/dynamic-query-with-search-container-liferay I have update my question