# Dynamic query with search container liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am facing problem in dynamic query. I didn't get any solution how can i do following query in liferay dynamic query.

```
mysql> select date_,count(*) from Clipping group by date_;
+---------------------+----------+
| date_               | count(*) |
+---------------------+----------+
| 2014-10-17 00:00:00 |        1 |
| 2014-10-24 00:00:00 |        2 |
| 2014-10-29 00:00:00 |        1 |
| 2014-11-15 00:00:00 |        1 |
| 2014-10-20 00:00:00 |        1 |
| 2014-10-24 00:00:00 |        1 |
| 2014-10-31 00:00:00 |        1 |
| 2014-10-10 00:00:00 |        1 |
| 2014-10-28 00:00:00 |        2 |
| 2014-10-15 00:00:00 |        2 |
| 2014-10-25 00:00:00 |        1 |
| 2014-11-20 00:00:00 |        1 |
| 2014-10-18 00:00:00 |        2 |
+---------------------+----------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I just want to set this record in my search container
How is it possible??
please help me
Thanks

Comment: Ah, LR and DynamicQurey... Glad I haven't used it for a year or so :-) Anyway, IIRC there should be a `dynamicQueryCount(query)` in your generated `LocalService`. Putting the `select date` into the DQ should be easy.

Comment: can you give me example please?